# Android - How to create a UI like the market or Shopsavvy

Tags: android, user-interface, interface, google-play

recently the android market and shopsavvy underwent UI overhauls. The result is a list then seems to slide under a curved top area with buttons on it. The top section seems to cast a slight dropshadow on the list and the list itsself has a different coloured heading to the rest of the list. It's a really big improvement on the look of android UI's , much more professional looking.

So how is the sliding under the curved top section with drop shadow achieved?

thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a great blog post by the developers that made the market app, and you can find it here http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/12/13/meet-the-green-goblin-part-1.html

At shopsavvy we took a much simpler approach and achieved generally the same results.  We use a frame layout with two sub layouts that overlap each other.  The top layout has as background that is a custom image that includes the shadow (we have an awesome graphics guy).  The bottom layout is simply a list view that has with a margin on top to place it where we want.  The pseudocode for it looks like this.

```
 <FrameLayout>
    <!-- Listview that sits under another view -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

         <ListView
           android:id="@+id/backgroundlist"
           android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <!-- view that sits on top -->
     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/curvedimage"
       android:orientation="vertical"
      >
        <!-- headers, buttons and other stuff -->
        <LinearLayout
          .....

     </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

For the heading on the listview you just use the addHeaderView function on a listview. You simply make a layout for the header that you want.  In our case we just use a text view with a different background color.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:text="@string/scans_right_now"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"

    android:paddingBottom="3dp"

    android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:shadowDx="0.0"
    android:shadowDy="1.0"
    android:shadowRadius="1.0" />
```

and then add that view as a header inside of your activity like so:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundlist);
View recentScansHeader =        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.recent_products_header, recentViewList, false);
list.addHeaderView(recentScansHeader);
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea you guys were on here. Getting a reply from the guys that actually did it is really excellent as is the reply itself. I'll have to knock up some test graphics and try this out. Thanks for the reply Brian